# Who were the founding members of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shield

S.H.I.E.L.D. was founded back in the 1900s in the MCU, and we know that Howard Stark and Peggy Carter were both founding members. **Is there a complete list of the founding members of S.H.I.E.L.D.?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the Agent Carter one-shot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Carter_(film)), we learn that Howard Stark intervenes in Peggy Carter’s SSR disciplinary action:

> the case line rings again, this time with Howard Stark on the other end, who informs Flynn that Carter will co-head the newly created S.H.I.E.L.D.

[The Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D.) confirms that [we learn the complete list of founding members from Captain America: The Winter Soldier:](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/)

> The founders of the new agency were Chester Phillips, the director of the SSR, Howard Stark, an industrialist of great wealth and a scientific genius, and Margaret "Peggy" Carter, the former partner of the American war hero Steve Rogers, better known as Captain America.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. How'd you dig it out? I couldn't find that...

Comment: First para. under “History” heading; that’s a pretty dense page with a lot of needless information in the upfront summary that is better located later down page.

Comment: You might want to quote from the one-shot ("[Agent Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Carter_(film))") rather than from the wiki